# Replace output of first command with output of second command in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

This function outputs a string 'hello' and replaces it with another string 'good-bye' on the same line in the terminal after 5 seconds:

```
echo -ne 'hello\r'; sleep 5; echo 'good-bye'
```

I have a situation where I'd like to achieve the same with the output of multiple `ls` commands. The `output` of the second `ls` command should replace the entire output of the first one.

**For example: (the execution I have in mind step by step)**

1. The script prints the output of the first `ls` command:

`someDir` `someFile1` `someFile2`

2. Waits for a key to be pressed. (Or like in the first example: sleeps for 5 seconds)
3. Erases the entire output of the first `ls` command (returns to the first position).
4. Then prints the output of the next `ls` command (In this case with `-l` option):

   - `someDir`
   - `someFile1`
   - `someFile2`

I thought this should work:

```
echo -en "$(ls)\r"; sleep 5; echo "$(ls -l)"
```

but it doesn't... This will just print the output two times, without replacing the first one with the second one.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this working (if possible at all)?

**Why do I need this?**

The idea behind this is to create a function, that lets you display the contents of a directory in different ways, by browsing through an array of ls commands with different option-sets using <kbd>k</kbd> / <kbd>j</kbd> to go forwards and backwards. That way you don't need to type in all the specific ls commands to get the output you want. You just browse to the option-set you need.

Comment: `\r` doesn't erase an arbitrary amount of previous output; it simply moves the cursor to the beginning of the *current* line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
ls | tr \\n \\r | sed 's/\r$/\
/'
```

where the `sed` substitution is typed in with `ctrl-v ctrl-j`.

But be careful what you wish for.  The effect is to leave on the line the overlaid text of the `ls` output.  The filenames are sorted, and printed over each other.  If the last one isn't the longest, the remnants of earlier ones will clutter the output:

```
$ ls -d Applications Documents willow | tr \\n \\r | sed 's/\r$/\  
/'
willowntsons
```

Comment: This code does only show the last line of the ls output (if I got it right). My idea is to replace the *entire* output of the first `ls` command with the *entire* output  of the second `ls` command. I updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> My idea is to replace the *entire* output of the first `ls` command with the *entire* output  of the second `ls` command.

```
#!/bin/zsh
output=(${(@f)"$(ls)"}) # read output lines into array
print -l $output
sleep 5
echoti cuu $#output     # move cursor up $#output lines
echoti ed               # clear to end of screen
ls -l
```